# The <h1> text is not changing color when clicked like it should

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to figure out why the color isn't changing when clicked on.

```js
function click(node) {
  var value = node.getAttribute('class') || '';
  value = value === '' ? 'clicked' : '';
  node.setAttribute('class', value);
  alert("hi")
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

h1 {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: black;
}

h1.clicked {
  color: navy;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" defer>
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 onclick="click(this)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </h1>
  <h2>Lorem esup poosum ait amet</h2>
  <h1 onclick="click(this)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </h1>
  <h2>Lorem esup poosum ait amet</h2>
  <h1 onclick="click(this)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </h1>
  <h2>Lorem esup poosum ait amet</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

I tested the function with an alert. I am fairly sure the problem lies with the function but I can't figure it out.

Comment: meant to type javascipt apologies

Answer (score 2):

In the inline event handler, `click` refers to the `click` function of the `<h1>` element itself (see [`HTMLElement#click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)). Either rename your function or use the modern `addEventListener` instead.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h1').forEach(h1 => h1.addEventListener('click', e => {
    h1.classList.toggle('clicked');
    alert("hi");
}));
```

```css
.clicked {color: dodgerblue;}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </h1>
<h2>Lorem esup poosum ait amet</h2>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </h1>
<h2>Lorem esup poosum ait amet</h2>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </h1>
<h2>Lorem esup poosum ait amet</h2>
```

Comment: Who are you and how do you have this knowledge???  ^0^